# Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement using dataframe.to_sql

Tags: mysql, sql, pandas, dataframe

I am having trouble diagnosing an error using pandas dataframe.to_sql

I first get my connection using `connection = mysql.connector.connect`

Then I try to insert my data into the mysql database using

`df.to_sql('SData', con = connection, if_exists = 'append', chunksize = 1000)`

I get the error:

`Execution failed on sql 'SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name=?;': Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement`

The SData table and the df have the same fields/names except the table has a primary key that is auto incremented so the only thing I can think of is that not all the fields match because of the primary key...

I'm also not understanding why there would be a select statement in the to_sql unless it is checking field names or something of that nature?

The data fields are:

```
Database:
SID Primary key
SSID int(foreign key)
FirstValue decimal
SecondValue decimal

DF:
FirstValue 
SecondValue 
SSID
```

While typing this I realized the dataframe is not the same order. Wouldnt think that would be an issue however will look into this

Thanks

Comment: have you tried creating your connection with [`sqlalchemy.create_engine`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/engines.html) instead?

Comment: Funny you mention that, doing that right now:)  Stand by

Comment: It got me further. I had to switch to pymysql to get it to work. Now I am getting the error "Unknown column 'index' in 'field list'". I suspect it has to do with the primary key in the database. Thanks:)

Answer (score 10):

The problem was I was trying to use `mysql.connector` as the connection(engine) and had to use sqlalchemy create_engine with mysql+pymysql.

I then had to_sql creating an index field so had to set index=False, and it worked.

Here is the new string:

```
import pymysql
engine = create_engine("mysql+pymysql://" + Cfg.username + ":" + Cfg.password + "@" + Cfg.host + "/" + Cfg.database)
df.to_sql('SData', con = engine, if_exists = 'append',index = False, chunksize = 1000)
```

Thanks

Comment: i  was also trying same, without knowing the correct method. It saves me, thanks a lot